# <memory> is not a BOMStorage file

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

When using a `UICollectionView` with a lot of cells that have images in it, I'm getting this odd warning in the log whenever an offscreen cell is scrolled to be onscreen:

```
2015-11-06 15:50:20.777 MyApp[49415:13109991] [/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI_Sim/CoreUI-370.8/Bom/Storage/BOMStorage.c:517] <memory> is not a BOMStorage file
```

Here's the cell setup:

```
import UIKit

class FeaturedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    private var xml: XMLIndexer? = nil

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // this enables the parallax type look
        self.imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = false
    }

    func loadImageFromUrlString(str: String) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: str) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.imageView.image = image

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
            }
        }
    }

    func setXml(xml: XMLIndexer) {
        self.xml = xml;

        if let imageUrl: String = (xml["FullAd"].element?.text)! {
            self.loadImageFromUrlString(imageUrl)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm still getting this warning.

Comment: @FayzaNawaz try loading the image asynchronously if you're not already.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to provide the solution. Instead, post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21723) this message is harmless.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but I've noticed that it results in a performance stutter whenever an image is displayed. The stutter is a ~1/10 second halt which wouldn't be noticeable except that the images are in a carousel so instead of being able to scroll quickly you are briefly interrupted over and over.

Comment: Through trial and error I've found that the interruption was due to loading the image synchronously, even if it was already loaded (which is odd). Switched to asynchronous and violá.

Comment: I'm loading the images asynchronous and still getting this messages :\. I'm using SDWebImage to get the images

Comment: If you're not getting a performance delay of any sort and it's just the warning then it's not going to effect your users at all. Until more information comes out on the subject we're kind of stuck with a useless message that doesn't actually do anything.